# Menu link not working properly on iPad

Tags: jquery, html, css, ipad, menu

I've got a "sticking to the top" menu in this website:

http://www.platform5.ch/~kda/

It works like a charm on desktop browsers, but on my iPad I realise that the menu links doesn't always work. Sometimes I need to scroll the page just a little bit to make it work.

Can anyone help with fixing this issue?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `position fixed` is not very well supported on mobile platforms: http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/ 
http://caniuse.com/css-fixed

Comment: @GeorgeReith good idea, I just added one

Comment: I see you tried to bind the scroll handler to touchmove event. with jquery mobile you should be able to capture a scrollstart and scrollstop event. From there you can bind your handler to touchmove or start a setInterval...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that this is a known bug in iOS. Elements with `position:fixed` don't handle 'click' and 'touch' events really well.

In fact, they don't detect these events after a "programmtical" scroll of the page. Only after a "manual" scroll do these elements react to clicks and touches (even a 1px scroll from the user).

I ended up giving up on the `position:fixed` and I use some JS to programmatically re-positioned the menu according the the scrollTop attribute of the window.